# What is the other "not merely vile, but horrific" tale about Tuon that Karede thinks about?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In Wheel of Time, Knife of Dreams, Chapter 34 "A Cup of *Kaf*", Furyk Karede thinks the following:

> It seemed everyone believed the filthy tale of Guards' involvement with a girl pretending to be the High Lady Tuon and extorting gold and jewels from merchants. Likely, they believed the other, whispered tale about the girl, not merely vile, but horrific.

What is this other tale? I can't recall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the same paragraph you're referencing:

> Likely they believed that other, whispered tale about the girl, not merely vile but horrific. No. **That the High Lady was in danger of her life from the Ever Victorious Army itself went beyond horrific**. That was a world gone mad.
>
> <sub>*Knife of Dreams, Chapter 34*</sub>

Comment: Is it? Karede muses to himself, that he dare not take the High Lady anywhere near Seanchan forces, because he is afraid they might not recognize here as the High Lady. The whole Mat and co going off into the woods, was because they heard that the Seanchan forces would kill the impostor on sight. To me, the whole scene - the EVA officers looking askance at the Deathwatch Guard - is that they think they have to do with the impostor, no?

Comment: @fbence, ah I think I understand. I have always assumed the fact that she was in danger from her own army was the horrific tale. You would say the whole `in danger of her life` bit is even worse than the `whispered tale`, and you want to know what that is?

Comment: Okay, so now I see, that the wording quite obviously implies, that the whispered tale is that the EVA would kill Tuon. But then I am really confused. They are also EVA, why would they be looking sideways at Karede for *that*? Or is this a reference to the mob that Mat destroys a few chapters later? But again, why would they look sides at Karede for that? Shouldn't they be ashamed rather? I think this is why I always thought there's some other tale :)

Comment: I think they thought the Deathwatch either killed Tuon, or failed in their duty to keep her safe. The latter would be one of the most dishonorable things a Deathwatch Guard could do